# Open source Graph-based SVM kernels

Tags: graph, classification, svm

Recent research proposes the classification or characterization of graphs (instead of flat feature vectors) with Support vector machines. Is there any open source available in C/C++ which can perform such classification?

Comment: That's very interesting! Can you please post a link to that paper?

Comment: @Pedrom. Spatio-spectral Remote Sensing Image Classification with Graph Kernels

Answer (score 0):

[ChemCPP](http://chemcpp.sourceforge.net/html/index.html) is oriented towards chemoinformatics but has some graph kernel computation code that you may find useful.

Karsten Borgwardt has done a lot of work on Graph Kernels. His page having code computing those kernels is [here](http://webdav.tuebingen.mpg.de/u/karsten/Forschung/research.html?page=research&topic=JMLR10_graphkernels&html=JMLR10).